# Laravel - How to Resolve Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string Error

Tags: laravel

When I run this code:

```
   public function manager_employee_list()
   {
       $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
       $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;
       $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();

       $linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();
       $linemanageremployee = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->get();  
       $goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $linemanageremployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', 
       return view('appraisal.appraisal_goals.manager_employee_list')->with('goals', $goals);        
}
```

I got this error:

Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

When I did:

> dd($linemanageremployee);

I got:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#880 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => {#2312 ▼
  +"id": 2
}
1 => {#2326 ▼
  +"id": 3
}
2 => {#2313 ▼
  +"id": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I resolve it?

Thank you.

Comment: [Try the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#retrieving-results). `get()` returns a collection, as your `dd()` shows.  A collection is like an array - not one thing, but a set of things.  In your example your DB query is returning 3 `id`s.  You need to iterate over each item in the collection to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
$linemanageremployee = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->get();
```

to

```
$linemanageremployee = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->pluck('id');
```

Then change:

```
$goals = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $linemanageremployee) ...
```

to

```
$goals = AppraisalGoal::whereIn('employee_id', $linemanageremployee) ...
```

---

#### Explanation:

`->get()` method returns an Eloquent Collection, which cannot be directly used inside of `where()` to make a query.

`->pluck()` method returns an array, which can be used to make a query with `whereIn()`

Comment: This may be the answer, but it would be much more helpful - for OP and future visitors - with an explanation of what you did and *why*.